# href mailto gets truncated in outlook

Tags: outlook, href

I'm running in to the following issue.
I'm working on a private intranet that makes use of user accounts. As administrator you are able to select a specific usergroup (or all) and puts all email adresses that are in the selected usergroup as a long string like so (clearly not the best way but it is what the clients budget allowed).

`<a href="mailto:test@test.nl; next@email.nl etc.etc.">Send mail</a>`

Now I'm not really sure what the issue is but somehow not all email adresses are send to outlook so they can send their 'newsletter' .

In total there should be 89 adressses containing 2206 characters. When I click the link only 2065 characters get trough.

When using this method over Imail it works fine but office keeps truncating in some way.

Does office only allow a max. count of characters at once in their Bcc? There is nothing I can find about this on the internet.

Hope you guys could help me out,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mots browsers limit the length of a url. In IE the max length is 2083 characters: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/208427/maximum-url-length-is-2-083-characters-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitry, strange thing is that it also in chrome and firefox. You know if there is also a limit on these browsers? Is there a fix/workaround for this? Thanks again.

Comment: Not much you can - mailto protocol is really not designed for things like that.

Comment: Thats a shame, Thanks alot.